# TDateTimePicker Show Time in Display and Can Edit Time

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to change the date format to show time
ie. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

but cannot edit the time

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify your required format using the [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.Format) property.

The other setting that is crucial is that you set the [`Kind`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.Kind) property to `dtkTime`. Without this change you will not be able to modify the time.

Comment: i have, i used the format above which is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", but the problem is i cannot change the time

Comment: Yeah, me too, works fine for me. I can't comment on what you did. You didn't give details in the question.

Comment: OK, I can see what has happened. You did not set `Kind` to `dtkTime`.